# Unknown custom element: <v-app> when use vuetify components

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am new for vuejs. I tried to create a calendar app with vue and vuetify, but got tons of error on console as blow photo:
I think they are from the same issue which I missed some config for vuetify. However, I tried to use the method I search from Google, like add "import "vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css";" and "Vue.use(Vuetify);". They are not working well.

[image]

This is vuetify.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from "vuetify/lib";

import "vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css";

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: "mdi",
  },
});
```

main.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import vuetify from "./plugins/vuetify";
import App from "./App.vue";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  vuetify,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Vuetify docs explain](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#webpack-install) how to set this up with webpack, which is what it looks like you're using.

`src/plugins/vuetify.js`

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

const opts = {}

export default new Vuetify(opts)
```

Your `main.js` is fine.

Alternatively, if you have the [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/) installed, then you can simply run:

```
vue add vuetify
```